# Arduino IDE #ifdef

Tags: arduino-ide, compile

I use my Arduino IDE to either upload my sketch to a Arduino or ATTiny or ATmega328. As you know each device can have a different pinout. Does the Arduino compiler support `ifdef`, depending on the board I am connected to?

For example

```
#ifdef Attiny85
       a=0; b=1; c=2;
#else
       // arduino
       a=9; b=10; c=11;
#endif
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Here is the syntax:

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
    //Code here
#endif
```

You can also do something like this for the Mega:

```
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
    //Code here
#endif
```

Assuming the implementation for the ATtiny is correct, your code should be like this:

```
#if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
       a=0; b=1; c=2;
#else
       //Arduino
       a=9; b=10; c=11
#endif
```

Comment: In `Arduino.h`, `__AVR_ATtiny85__` is used (capital `T`). Not sure if it makes any difference though.

Comment: alternatively using 1.5.+ IDE you can test against the board type you are building. See [Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification#boardstxt). Example "#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO)" or ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 or ARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO, etc...